# AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 (13)Permission denied

Tags: apache, macos-sierra

After upgrading to `macOS Sierra` my apache doesn't start.

Where it goes the apache `error_log`:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist

AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist

AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for username.local

AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message (13)Permission denied:

AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 (13)Permission denied: 

AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down*
```

I already follow these instructions without success: http://digitalshore.io/local-web-development-environment-apache-macos-sierra-10-12/

Comment: for first 2 comment dummy host setting in httpd-vhosts.conf
for 3,4 uncomment ServerName and assign value in httpd.conf ex:  ServerName local_server:80 and add the same value in /etc/hosts to access by server name

Comment: For me I had only first two errors; @NagaPenmetsa answers solved that for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For first 2 comment dummy host setting in

> httpd-vhosts.conf

For 3,4 uncomment ServerName and assign value in

> httpd.conf
>
> ex: ServerName local_server:80

And add the same value in /etc/hosts to access by server name.

5,6 because port 80 is used by other application

> sudo lsof -i:80

Comment: I'm getting a similar kind of error. Here is my SO link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559201/mac-os-sierra-error-httpd-apr-sockaddr-info-get-failed-could-not-reliably-de .Any idea what's cause of this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Errors involving `apr_sockaddr_info_get()` may be resolved by assigning a meaningful value (such as `localhost`) for `ServerName` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Open `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` using `sudo`.

Reference:
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

Comment: "apr_sockaddr_info_get()" got resolved by adding localhost as ServerName

Answer (score 1):

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name.

You need to identify `httpd.conf` Apache configuration file by:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

then edit it and uncomment the line with `ServerName` (make sure it has the valid server name). E.g.

```
ServerName localhost
```

> AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 (13) Permission denied

You need to launch Apache service as root user, otherwise the process doesn't have permission to bind to port 80 since all ports below 1024 needs administrative permissions.

So you need run it as:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was resolved by adding:

```
127.0.0.1       MacBook-Air-de-xxxxxx.local
```

in `/etc/hosts` file.

The find the exact name of the computer, check in the settings of sharing:

[image]