# Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name for MacBook

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, macos-sierra

First time got a new MBP 2016. Trying to setup PHP,MySQL & Apache. Started Apache by using command

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Then installed PHP by

```
brew install php71 --with-httpd24
```

Also did following changes...

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

ServerName dev-server
```

Also, updated the same in host file `/etc/hosts/`

But, whenever I'm trying to Stop/Restart my apache by using command `sudo apachectl restart` or `sudo apachectl stop` I'm getting following errors.

```
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for Sureshs-MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd not running, trying to start
```

But, strangely when I'm executing any PHP file from my browser `http://localhost/index.php` it's working fine. As in my index.php file I'm using code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` It's showing PHP version `PHP Version 7.1.4` loaded.

Tried a lot but no clude what's going wrong at where.

**---UPDATE---**

After updating `127.0.0.1 Sureshs-MacBook-Pro.local` in my `/private/etc/hosts` file, one error solved. Now I'm getting only one below error.

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Sureshs-MacBook-Pro.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Comment: Adding a `serverName = my.server.name` directive to your apache config might resolve the warning you are getting.

Comment: I've already added that as ```ServerName dev-server```. See my post

Comment: Try ServerName value without hyphen and give port value. Ex: ServerName devserver:80

Comment: @NagaPenmetsa I've finally fig out what's was the issue in my case. I've already replied the answer in the post. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 29):

Finally, I solved this by updating `ServerName localhost:8080` on file `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf`. It was a differnt httpd.conf file which I didn't knew about it.

Also, for Apache `start/restart/stop` following command `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl start` works for me.

Comment: I tried all what you sugegsted but still have same issue, if I do php -v I see proper php 7 version but can't make apache to restart always ends up with this error AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using vaske-mbp.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message. I extended etc hosts by adding 127.0.0.1 vaske-mbp.local but it didn't helped at all.

Comment: Thanks... For mac users: you can find your `httpd.conf` file at path `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 24):

As per message:

> Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message.

You need to identify `httpd.conf` Apache configuration file by:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

then edit it and uncomment the line with `ServerName` (make sure it has the valid server name). E.g.

```
ServerName localhost
```

Comment: I was making changes to some other httpd.conf and was about to throw away my mac as I wasn't getting any changes. You saved my mac! :D Thanka alot. Also it would be helpful if you could tell how to change the path of httpd.conf file for apache

Comment: thanks so much! there are so many httpd.conf files floading around that i was not sure which one was the one that is actually used :)

Answer (score 6):

open file httpd.conf

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

add to first line

```
ServerName localhost
```

systemctl restart httpd

Answer (score 0):

**I resolved this issue changing the port address in the httpd.conf file in windows.**

This problem arises due to the port already listening, which we use in the conf file.

To view the port listening, use the command "netview /a"

**if the port used in the conf file already listening, change to different one(e.g, 8080)**

set servername to "localhost" or 127.0.0.1

Now start the apache server "httpd.exe -k start"

it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Catalina...

**Edit the Apache config file**

`sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Find the ServerName entry by typing a `/` followed by `ServerName` and hit `enter`

Press `n` to go to the next occurrence until you are on `#ServerName www.example.com:80` (keep pressing `n` if you go past it)

Add a newline by typing an `o`

Type the following: `ServerName localhost`

Save and exit by typing `!wq` then hit enter (or type `ZZ` which is capital Z twice)

**Restart Apache**

`sudo apachectl restart`